# How to change unnest cell array into a lined up formation?

Tags: matlab

I have the following 2 x 1 cell C

```
Text1
Text2
```

And I wanted to write out this in the following line up and store it in the Variable Container:

```
Container = {'Text';'Text2'};
```

a.)Is there a command which leds me write out this desired line up (including the brackets as well as the semicolons)?

b.)How can expand this little example for more than 2 rows?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Do you just want to concatenate all text, separated by `';'`, and surround it by brackets? Or transpose your cell array?

Comment: Your first snippet already looks like a 2x1 cell array, the same as your `Container` output that you want to obtain. So it's not clear what you want. Please explain it better, and post an actual example defining the input data and the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the text representation of the cell array you can use [`strjoin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html):

```
Container = ['{''' strjoin(C, ''';''') '''}'];
```

It is assumed that the cell array contains only character strings and it isn't empty.